# format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *'

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    char st;
    printf("enter string\n");
    scanf("%s", st);
    printf("the entered string is %s\n", st);
}
```

Compiling above program gives me a warning:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
palindrom.c:8:1: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is what happens when I run it:

```
$ ./a.out
enter string
kiaaa
the entered string is (null)
```

**Edit:**

Here is another version of the code (made `char st;` into `char *st`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    char *st;
    printf("enter string\n");
    scanf("%s", st);
    printf("the entered string is %s\n", st);
}
```

However, it behaves the same on runtime.

Comment: Now your `char *st;` is an uninitialised pointer. You don't know where it points. Accessing it in the `scanf` is undefined behaviour. You must make it point to a sufficiently large chunk of valid memory. Either declare an array `char st[100];` - the array name is converted to a pointer when passed as an argument to `scanf` or `printf`, so that's fine - or declare it as a pointer, like you have, and allocate some memory, `st = malloc(100 * sizeof *st);` before using it. You need `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`, and check whether `malloc` returned `NULL`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`char st` is a single character. Judging by the rest of your code, you probably intended to declare an array of characters:

```
char st[80];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a type mis-match.
`scanf`is not type safe, You need to provide proper type. `scanf` enables you to get data  from the input and you need to tell it what is the type of the data you want it to read. You ask it to read a string by specifying `%s` by provide it with a character variable.

You need an array:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 256
char st[MAX_LENGTH];
```

As @Jerry rightly points out, You can just simple avoid all the hassle by using:
**getline()** instead of using `scanf`

Comment: ...and then specify the maximum length when you call `scanf` -- as is, the call with just `%s` instead of something like `%255s` is roughly equivalent to calling `gets`.

Comment: That certainly wasn't intended as recommending that anybody use `gets` (ever)!

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Hmm..yup..slipped.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` needs a pointer to `char*` to indicate you are scanning a string.

You are supplying a character that's allocated on the stack.

You either want to use a `getchar()` or make `st` a char array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `char *st;` or an array like `char st[50];`.

When you complete the usage of a char pointer, you should deallocate the memory used by the pointer. This can be done using `free(st);` function.

EDIT : As you are printing string and if you are using pointer, you can do:

```
printf("the entered string is %s\n",st);
printf("the entered string is %s\n",*st); // This will work in both cases, if you use char *st or char st[50]
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend `char*`, please also recommend a way to allocate/free memory.

Comment: If I use it like char *st then how should I go for this to print?

`char *st;
printf("enter string\n");
scanf("%s",st);
printf("the entered string is %s\n",*st);`

Comment: @RegisteredUser : go ahead with your solution. or you also can use printf("the entered string is %s\n",st);

Comment: @Nandkumar but in my solution it does not gives the string as output you can run the code `#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
 int i,j,k;
 char *st;
printf("enter string\n");
scanf("%s",st);
printf("the entered string is %s\n",st);
}` this gives a null

Comment: There is really no reason to use dynamic allocation for this example.

Comment: @Lundin : Yeah I agree with you. But solution should be complete. Also I don't know, what would be the length of string user is entering, therefore...

Comment: idk what's that garbage about `*st`, this answer is not good .

Answer (score 0):

st is type of char
&st is type of char *
Take care of the difference.
BTW, only one char cannot be used to store a string. Use char[] array.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you want to create an array:

Change `char st;` to `char st[10];` or whatever size array you want.

With the above change `st` is an array that has 10 individual elements that can hold a single char value.

Answer (score 0):

char st is a character i.e it will store only one character try it like this
`main()
 char st [100];
 scanf("%s",st);`
just change these three lines and it will work it will except only single word strings
here you have declared the function as an int that is int main() keep it as main() and it will work