# format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **'

Tags: c, warnings

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *bitstr;

    printf("Enter a bitstring or q for quit: ");
    scanf("%s", &bitstr);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep receive the following error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but 
argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
```

Comment: error msg seems self-explanatory...

Comment: You also need to initialize `bitstr` with `malloc()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char \*’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732010/format-s-expects-argument-of-type-char)

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example: scanf and char errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380933/example-scanf-and-char-errors)

Answer (score 1):

1 **Pass address** of a `char` array in `scanf()` and not the address of a `char*`.
2 **Insure you do not overwrite** your destination buffer.
3 **Right-size your buffer needs**.  It is apparent from other posts you want a binary textual representation of an `int`.  Let's assume your `int` is 8 bytes (64 bits).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char bitstr[8*8 + 1];  // size to a bit representation of a big integer.
    printf("Enter a bitstring or q for quit: ");
    //Change format and pass bitscr, this results in the address of bitscr array.
    scanf("%64s", bitstr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

I prefer the fgets() & sscanf() method.

```
char buf[100];  // You can re-use this buffer for other inputs.
if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) { ; /*handle error or EOF */ }
sscanf(buf, "%64s", bitstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(){
    char bitstr[MAX] = "";

    printf("Enter a bitstring or q for quit: ");
    scanf("%s", &bitstr);

    // or fgets(bitstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Try to define or allocate the size of your string/char array.

Comment: `#define 100 MAX` should be `#define MAX 100`, and suggest  `fgets();` instead of `gets(bitstr);` and `scanf("%s", &bitstr);`

Comment: Nope. `&bitstr` is of type `char (*)[100]`; `%s` requires an argument of type `char*`. Drop the `&`: `scanf("%s", bitstr)`; `bitstr` is of array type, and it decays to a pointer to the array's first element. Important note: Both `scanf("%s", ...)` and `gets()` are inherently unsafe, so much so that `gets` has been dropped from the language. They cannot guard against overly long input.